# Pass results of querySelectorAll to EventTarget.addEventListener

Tags: reason, bucklescript, bs-webapi

I want to do something like:

```
open Webapi.Dom;

let addListener = (element) =>
    EventTarget.addEventListener("click", onSubscribeClick, EventTarget.asEventTarget(element));

let addOrRemoveListeners = (handler, ()) => {
    let elements = Document.querySelectorAll({j|[$subscriptionIdAttr]|j}, document);
    Js.Array.forEach(handler, NodeListRe.toArray(elements) |> Js.Array.map(Element.ofNode))
  };

let addListeners = addOrRemoveListeners(addListener);

let removeListeners = addOrRemoveListeners(removeListener);
```

But I get an error in `addOrRemoveListeners(addListener);`:

```
This is:
  (Dom.eventTarget) => unit
But somewhere wanted:
  (Dom.node) => unit
```

How should I convert from `Dom.eventTarget` to `Dom.node`?

---

Edit: I ended up with this:

```
let addListener = Element.addEventListener("click", onSubscribeClick);
let removeListener = Element.removeEventListener("click", onSubscribeClick);
let addOrRemoveListeners = (handler, ()) => {
  let elements = Document.querySelectorAll({j|[$(subscriptionIdAttr)]|j}, document);
  let () =
    elements
    |> NodeListRe.toArray
    |> Array.map(Element.ofNode)
    |> Array.to_list
    |> List.filter(Js.Option.isSome)
    |> List.map(Js.Option.getExn)
    |> List.iter(handler);
  ()
};
let addListeners = addOrRemoveListeners(addListener);
let removeListeners = addOrRemoveListeners(removeListener);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer:

```
external eventTargetToNode : Dom.eventTarget => Dom.node = "%identity";
```

An `eventTarget` can be almost anything, and there's unfortunately no good way of figuring out what it is. In JavaScript it's simply inferred by the user based on context (It might be possible to carry that context around in a type parameter, but that's off in the future somewhere).

So for the moment you'll have to make an unsafe cast to get what you need.

(BTW, you can use `Element.addEventListener` to avoid the cast from `element` to `eventTarget`)

Comment: thanks! I didn't now `Element` also had `addEventListener` available.

I am not able to get the option from `Element.ofNode` though:

    `let addOrRemoveListeners = (handler) => {
      let elements = Document.querySelectorAll({j|[$dataAttrProductId]|j}, document);
      let handleOptElement = (element: option(Element.t)) =>
        switch element {
        | None => (element => ())
        | Some(_element) => handler
        };
      let _ =
      Array.iter(handleOptElement, NodeListRe.toArray(elements) |> 
  Array.map(Element.ofNode));
      ()
    };`

Do you know why?

Comment: I get a `This is:
  (option(Webapi.Dom.Element.t), 'a) => unit
But somewhere wanted:
  (option(Webapi.Dom.Element.t)) => unit` error when using `handleOptElement` as first param of `Array.iter`.

Comment: Finally fixed it, I was missing the unit param on `addOrRemoveListener` :) I updated the question with the full code.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't realize you were still stuck. I thought this was the same question you asked on Discord...